# HTML5 API's Content Assist does not work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, eclipse-wtp

I had installed the **html5wtp 0.36** in Eclipse Indigo SR2

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/html5wtp

If i try using the below code in the HTML page, no HTML5 API's are displayed in the   javascript Content Assist.

**var elcanvas=document.getElementById('canvas');**

var context=elcanvas.getContext("2d");

Kindly let me know is there any solution for the Content Assist problem.

Comment: I am also trying to find out the same.